# Scroll position issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the link to my project : http://ryanrobert91.com/project/artic.co/index.html

1.As you can see from my project above, i don't know it is a bug or what... which whenever i loaded the website, and go to the next page and it  have the scrollTop animate but the position does't seem right for the first time and the scrollTop does execute... but after clicking back and forward the second time, the position does seem right.

2.the size of the browser also effect the position. when i using my bigger monitor the position does seem right but when i open it on my smaller laptop screen the position is off.

And if you dont understand my explanation just go to the link and play around the site and you will notice the problem as well.

please help me with this, and if you want more part of the coding just tell me.

here are my code :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){



    $('body').animate({scrollTop: $("#b1").offset().top},1);
    b1Slide('b1');
var status = $('#remote').data('level') ;
   var next = document.getElementById('next');
var prev = document.getElementById('prev');
    var ccc = 1;

    $("#next").click(function() {              
       if(status == 1 ){
    $('body').animate({scrollTop: $("#b2").offset().top},900);
           prev.style.display = "block";
           b1Slide('b2');
           b1Slide_b('b1');

           status = 2;
       }
         else if(status == 2) {
            $('body').animate({scrollTop: $("#b3").offset().top},900);
             b1Slide('b3');
             b1Slide_b('b2');

           status = 3;
       }

          else if(status == 3) {
            $('body').animate({scrollTop: $("#b4").offset().top},900);
              b1Slide('b4');
              b1Slide_b('b3');

           status = 4;
              next.style.display = "none";
       }
         else{}

        });

     $("#prev").click(function() {              
       if(status == 1 ){

       }
        else if(status == 2){
            $('body').animate({scrollTop: $("#b1").offset().top},900);
            b1Slide('b1');
            b1Slide_b('b2');
           status = 1;
            prev.style.display = "none";
        }  
          else if(status == 3){
            $('body').animate({scrollTop: $("#b2").offset().top},900);
              b1Slide('b2');
            b1Slide_b('b3');
           status = 2;
        }  
           else if(status == 4){
            $('body').animate({scrollTop: $("#b3").offset().top},900);
               b1Slide('b3');
            b1Slide_b('b4');
           status = 3;
               next.style.display = "block";
        }    
         else{}
     }); 


});
```

Comment: which browsers do you have this problem on?

Comment: all browser ......................... but i think there something wrong with my code